# My simple akka actor test is failing, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to test this simple actor:

```
object Notify {
  def props(incidentId: Int): Props = Props(new Notify(incidentId: Int))


  final case class Send(reportId: Int)
}

class Notify(incidentId: Int) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import Notify._

  log.info("Notify constructor...")

//  val x = 0
//  val y = 123 / x

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Send(reportId) =>
      log.debug(s"Notify Send $reportId")
  }

}
```

I get this error:

> - should e f g *** FAILED *** [info]   java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting
>     for Send(123) [info]   at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
>     [info]   at
>     akka.testkit.TestKitBase$class.expectMsg_internal(TestKit.scala:402)
>     [info]   at
>     akka.testkit.TestKitBase$class.expectMsg(TestKit.scala:379) [info]
>     at akka.testkit.TestKit.expectMsg(TestKit.scala:896) [info]   at
>     TestKitUsageSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$5.apply(ActorSpec.scala:49)
>     [info]   at
>     TestKitUsageSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$5.apply(ActorSpec.scala:47)
>     [info]   at
>     org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85) [info]
>     at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104) [info]   at
>     org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22) [info]   at
>     org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)

My akka test setup looks like this:

```
import scala.util.Random

import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll
import org.scalatest.WordSpecLike
import org.scalatest.Matchers

import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.testkit.{ TestActors, DefaultTimeout, ImplicitSender, TestKit, TestProbe }
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.collection.immutable

import com.example.notifications._

class TestKitUsageSpec
  extends TestKit(ActorSystem(
    "TestKitUsageSpec",
    ConfigFactory.parseString(TestKitUsageSpec.config)))
    with DefaultTimeout with ImplicitSender
    with WordSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {
  import TestKitUsageSpec._

  val echoRef = system.actorOf(TestActors.echoActorProps)
  val forwardRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[ForwardingActor], testActor))
  val filterRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[FilteringActor], testActor))
  val randomHead = Random.nextInt(6)
  val randomTail = Random.nextInt(10)
  val headList = immutable.Seq().padTo(randomHead, "0")
  val tailList = immutable.Seq().padTo(randomTail, "1")
  val seqRef =
    system.actorOf(Props(classOf[SequencingActor], testActor, headList, tailList))

  val notifyActor = system.actorOf(Notify.props(123))

  override def afterAll {
    shutdown()
  }

  "a b c d " should {
    "e f g" in {
      notifyActor ! Notify.Send(123)
      expectMsg(Notify.Send(123))
    }
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you're testing that `Notify` echoes its `Send` messages back to the sender (`expectMsg(Notify.Send(123))`), but all the `Notify` actor does is to log its received `Send` messages while doing nothing else. Consequently, the `expectMsg` call times-out, as nothing is sent back, producing the exception in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your test you're sending a message to your actor (`notifyActor ! Notify.Send(123)`) and then you test whether your actor responds with the same message (`expectMsg(Notify.Send(123))`).

Your example actor does not responde to requests. Therefore your test gives up waiting for a response with a timeout exception at some time.

To get your test running, you must let your actor respond to requests.
You could do this by adding to the receive method: `sender ! Notify.Send(123)`.

Comment: what if my actor doesn't respond, can I test it received the message?

Comment: Testing whether an Actor receives a message is a test of akka framework itself, not for your logic embedded within the framework. This is not the focus of Akka's testkit.

Comment: @Blankman If you want to test that it has received a message, it's necessary for the `Notify` agent to send back some form of acknowledgement message to the sender of the messages it processes. You can then test for the acknowledgement using `expectMsg`. For instance, you could have an `Ack` case class whose argument is the message received; sending back such an instance of that as a message to the sender would be a way to prove that you processed the message correctly. That might not be appropriate for the production version of your code. Alternatively, check `Notify`'s log for the message.